# Pipe Pyspark OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, apache-spark, winapi, pyspark, rdd

I have installed Spark 3.0.0 on a Windows 64 bit machine with Python 3.9.7 using an `anaconda` base environment.
I'm trying to execute the next code in the `pyspark` shell to test the RDD pipe method.

```py
myCollection = "Spark the Definitive Guide : Big Data as Made Simple".split(" ")
words = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(myCollection,2)
words.pipe("echo hello").collect()
```

Then, I get the following error when catching the `pipe()` call.

```
  File "C:\Users\aitor.hernandez\Spark3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 597, in main
  File "C:\Users\aitor.hernandez\Spark3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 587, in process
  File "C:\Users\aitor.hernandez\Spark3\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 425, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\aitor.hernandez\Spark3\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 827, in func
    pipe = Popen(
  File "C:\Users\aitor.hernandez\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\aitor.hernandez\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I've tried changeing the parameter "shell" to `true` to init Popen objects.

I've also reviewed similiar issues but the most are about specific packages. None of them resolve this case. Does anyone know what happened and how I can resolve it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's a python version issue. May be ur using old windows system. So python 3.8 or 3.9 is not workings. Try to install python 3.6 or near version it's working.
My old system also got the same issue, scala spark working fine but pyspark 3.8 not working, but when I changed python version 3.6 working fine. Try your end as well.